# MySQL column names

Tags: mysql

Im trying to write a query in MySQL however one fo my column names is 'comment' however when entered into a WHERE clause it shows up bold and doesn't get used as a column name does anyone know how to change that?

this is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT propertyNo from Viewing 
WHERE comment  IS NULL 

UNION 

SELECT propertyNo FROM PropertyForRent
WHERE rent < 600
ORDER BY propertyNO ASC;
```

Comment: You have to post the code you want to change before someone can tell you how to change it.

Comment: @ScottHunter I've edited the question now

Comment: Try using back-tics (`) around the field.

Comment: COMMENT is a keyword but not a reserved word: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-C In any case enclose it in backticks.

Comment: `COMMENT` is a [key word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) and must be quoted to be used as an identifier.

Comment: What is your schema?

Comment: As other comments and answers have already stated, you can delimit field names with backticks. I'd go a step further, and some would disagree, and say it's a good practice to always delimit your identifiers that way. It makes for a more consistent style when using them is necessary, and future proofs your queries better (it isn't often, but new keywords are added occasionally).

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote it:

```
WHERE `comment`  IS NULL
```

This is covered in the [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) sections of the [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/).

Answer (score 1):

Always use backticks and quotation marks when you write your SQL.

With ` you write variable names

With ' you write variable values

For example

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `x` = 'blahblah'
```

Comment: I'd agree with the backticks part; but quoting numeric values is unnecessary (unless the field containing them isn't numeric) and can lead to weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT is a keyword in MySQL. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-C

That's why your editor shows it as bold. You can escape this by using back ticks:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `propertyNo` from `Viewing` 
WHERE `comment`  IS NULL
```

Try to always use back ticks when referring to columns or table names. More info on that subject: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/benefits-of-using-backtick-in-mysql-queries/23130